# MySql - Pivot Table

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, pivot, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to pull some data out of the wp_postmeta table which is basically a series of key/value pairs tied to a numeric post_id. As such, when I try to extract various values for a post, this is what I get:

[image: results im getting]

This is the current query I'm using to get that output:

```sql
select post_id,meta_key,meta_value from wp_postmeta
where meta_key in ('_sku','_length','_width','_height')
and post_id in (
    select post_id from wp_postmeta
    where meta_value in ('28-005080','28-005287')
    )
    order by post_id DESC
```

What I'm trying to do is format the information like this:

[image: results i want]

I've tried to look at the MySql pivot table examples, but I'm not sure if they quite fit this specific scenario. Frankly, I don't know where to start with accomplishing this task.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Forgive me, but what exactly do you mean by this suggestion?

Comment: You mentioned Wordpress, so evidently you have some access to /awareness of things beyond MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select post_id,
    max(case when meta_key = '_sku'    then meta_value end) as sku,
    max(case when meta_key = '_length' then meta_value end) as length,
    max(case when meta_key = '_width'  then meta_value end) as width,
    max(case when meta_key = '_height' then meta_value end) as height
from wp_postmeta
where 
    meta_key in ('_sku','_length','_width','_height')
    and post_id in (select post_id from wp_postmeta where meta_value in ('28-005080','28-005287'))
group by post_id
order by post_id desc
```

Actually, we might be able to replace the subquery in the `where` clause with a `having` clause:

```
select post_id,
    max(case when meta_key = '_sku'    then meta_value end) as sku,
    max(case when meta_key = '_length' then meta_value end) as length,
    max(case when meta_key = '_width'  then meta_value end) as width,
    max(case when meta_key = '_height' then meta_value end) as height
from wp_postmeta
group by post_id
having max(meta_value in ('28-005080','28-005287')) = 1
order by post_id desc
```